# How to use a .raw file in opengl

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to read a `.raw` image format and do some modifications on it in OpenGL. I can read the image like this:

```
int width, height;
BYTE * data;
FILE * file;

file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
if ( file == NULL ) return 0;

width = 256;
height = 256;
data = malloc( width * height * 3 );

fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
fclose( file );
```

But i dont know how to use `glDrawPixels` to draw the picture.

My second problem is that I dont know how can I access each pixel. I mean in a `.raw` image format, each pixel should have 3 integers for storing `RGB` values(Am I right?). How can I access these RGB values directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a .raw in the hard and fast sense. The name implies image data with no header but doesn't specify the format of the data. RGB is likely but so is RGBA and it's trivial to think of almost endless other possibilities.

Assuming RGB ordering, one byte per channel, then: each pixel is three bytes wide. So the nth pixel is:

```
r = data[n*3 + 0]
g = data[n*3 + 1]
b = data[n*3 + 2]
```

Assuming the data is set out so that the pixels are stored in left-to-right order, line by line, then on the first line the pixel at x=3 is at n=3, on the second it's at n=(width of first line)+3, on the third it's at n=(combined width of first two lines)+3, etc.

So:

```
r = data[(x + y*width)*3 + 0]
g = data[(x + y*width)*3 + 1]
b = data[(x + y*width)*3 + 2]
```

To use `glDrawPixels` just follow what [the manual](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml) tells you to specify as the parameters. It says:

```
void glDrawPixels(  GLsizei     width,
                    GLsizei     height,
                    GLenum      format,
                    GLenum      type,
                    const GLvoid *      data);
```

You say that width and height are 256. You've said that the format is RGB. Scan down the documentation and you'll see that the corresponding `GLenum` is `GL_RGB`. You're saying each channel is a single byte in size. So that's `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`. You've loaded the data to `data`. So:

```
glDrawPixels(256, 256, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Further comments: obviously get this working first so you've something to build on but `glDrawPixels` is almost unused in practice. As a result it isn't even part of OpenGL ES or, correspondingly, WebGL. Look at the semantics of the thing. You supply your buffer every time you call. OpenGL can't know whether it has been modified since the last call. So every call transfers your data from CPU to GPU. Look into submitting your data once as a texture and drawing using geometry. That'll save the per-call transfer cost and therefore be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Where does the OP say that width and height are **257**? That would actually be very disconcerting because aside from being an ugly non-power-of-two dimension, **257**x**3** mod **4** != **0**. That means the default pixel unpack alignment (4-bytes per-row) would be incorrect and the image would come out a slanted disaster with each row of the image beginning in the wrong place ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman typo fixed. But, yes, some mention of `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` would have been required. Or merely a reference to e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042027/glpixelstoreigl-unpack-alignment-1-disadvantages