# PNG saved from OpenGL framebuffer using stbi_write_png is shifted to the right

Tags: c++, opengl, png, fbo, stb-image

I have been trying to solve this visual bug for a few days without any success, so I'm asking this question to see if somebody can help me understand what is happening.

First I will describe the problem without any code, and then I will present some code. Here is the situation:

- My OpenGL application renders this image to a multisample framebuffer:

  [image]
- I then blit that multisample framebuffer into a regular framebuffer (not a multisample one).
- I then read the RGB data from that regular framebuffer into an array of unsigned bytes using `glReadPixels`.
- Finally, I call `stbi_write_png` with the array of unsigned bytes. This is the result:

  [image]

To me it looks like the first line of bytes is shifted to the right, which causes all the other lines to be shifted, resulting in a diagonal shape.

Here is my code:

- To create the multisample framebuffer:

```cpp
   int width        = 450;
   int height       = 450;
   int numOfSamples = 1;

   // Create the multisample framebuffer

   glGenFramebuffers(1, &mMultisampleFBO);

   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mMultisampleFBO);

   // Create a multisample texture and use it as a color attachment
   glGenTextures(1, &mMultisampleTexture);

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, mMultisampleTexture);
   glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, numOfSamples, GL_RGB, width, height, GL_TRUE);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);

   glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, mMultisampleTexture, 0);

   // Create a multisample renderbuffer object and use it as a depth attachment
   glGenRenderbuffers(1, &mMultisampleRBO);

   glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, mMultisampleRBO);
   glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, numOfSamples, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
   glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

   glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, mMultisampleRBO);
```

- To create the regular framebuffer:

```cpp
   // Create the regular framebuffer

   glGenFramebuffers(1, &mRegularFBO);

   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mRegularFBO);

   // Create a texture and use it as a color attachment
   glGenTextures(1, &mRegularTexture);

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mRegularTexture);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

   glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, mRegularTexture, 0);
```

- Note that both framebuffers are reported as complete.
- To blit the multisample framebuffer into the regular one, read from the regular one and write the PNG image:

```cpp
   int width  = 450;
   int height = 450;
   static GLubyte* data = new GLubyte[3 * 450 * 450];
   memset(data, 0, 3 * width * height);

   // Blit the multisample framebuffer into the regular framebuffer
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, mMultisampleFBO);
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, mRegularFBO);
   glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

   // Read from the regular framebuffer into the data array
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mRegularFBO);
   glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

   // Write the PNG image
   int numOfComponents = 3; // RGB
   int strideInBytes   = width * 3;
   stbi_write_png(imgName.c_str(), width, height, 3, data, width * 3);
```

- Note that glGetError reports no errors.

I haven't been able to figure out what is wrong. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Looks like there's padding at the end of each line.  Since one line is 450*3 = 1250 bytes, there are 2 padding bytes that you don't account for when writing the PNG.  Change the stride to `width * 3 + 2` (although that `2` should be calculated and not hard coded).

Comment: By default, rows are aligned on 4 bytes. Your `write_png` call expects one contiguous block. set GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT to 1 as per this question: [glPixelStorei(GL\_UNPACK\_ALIGNMENT, 1) Disadvantages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042027/glpixelstoreigl-unpack-alignment-1-disadvantages)

Comment: dump out a raw image at each stage and find out where the stride is going wrong

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Your solution also fixes my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, that is what I said. The question I linked just happens to talk about UNPACK* :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is cause be the alignment of a row, when the image is read by [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml). By default the alignment of the start of each row of the image is assumed to be 4.
Since the width of the image is 450, which is not divisible by 4 (450/4 = 112.5) and the format is RGB (3 bytes), the alignment has to be changed.

Change the `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` ([`glPixelStore`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml))  before reading the image data:

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```